# jquery ajax was stuck, showing "Request not finished yet" in the network panel, though there is already response header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, header, response

I met a very confusing problem. In my application, I use javascript AJAX to send an API request, but it seems to be stuck often. Whenever the issue happens, it shows "Request not finished yet" in the network panel. However, as I check the request in the network panel, there is already response header.

[image: A pending request]

[image]

[image]

I have checked the [explanation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation), but i don't see any simultaneous multiple requests during this api. Also, since there is already response header, it seems to be very reasonable that the request is end. Why does the request never finish? Is there any suggestion to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: this sometimes happens when response content is too large to download within seconds or network connection is too slow to download the content in that time period. While all the contents is not downloaded this caution will show!

Comment: @HelloWorld thank you for your response. When I tried sending the request in the POSTMAN or directly from browser, it responses within 0.7s. it should be no delay at all. is there any way to find the difference between these two situations?

Comment: Have you cross checked the headers you are sending via AJAX with those in postman?